# window.location open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `select` list that go to external link when I clicked go button. But the link opens in same window. I want to make it open new window. Here is my code.

```
 <select id="my-dropdown" name="my-dropdown">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="http://www.aol.com">B</option>
 </select>
 <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>
```

Javascript :

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
   window.location = $('#my-dropdown').val();
});
```

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Some of the suggested answers trigger a pop up blocker. Is that an issue for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make it

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
   window.open( $('#my-dropdown').val() );
});
```

or

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
   window.open( $('#my-dropdown').val(), "_newtab" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this too

```
window.open($('#my-dropdown').val(), '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `window.open()`:

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
 window.open($('#my-dropdown').val(), '_blank');
});
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jsarnaff/)

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript solution:

```
<select id="my-dropdown" name="my-dropdown">
  <option value="www.google.com">A</option>
  <option value="www.aol.com">B</option>
</select>
<button class="go-btn" type="button" onclick="go();">Go</button>

<script>
  function go() {
    var e = document.getElementById("my-dropdown");
    var url = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    window.open(url, "_newtab");
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please check this

```
<select id="my-dropdown">                     
    <option value="http://www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">B</option>
</select>
<button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.go-btn').click(function() {
      window.open($('#my-dropdown').val(), '_blank');
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach that does not trigger the browsers pop up blockers as `window.open` sometimes can.

Dynamically create a link with your dropdown's values as well as `target="_blank"` and then force a click on it.

See it on [jsbin](https://output.jsbin.com/seqifa)

```js
    var setAttributes = function(d, b) {
  for (var h in b) b.hasOwnProperty(h) && d.setAttribute(h, b[h]);
  return d;
};

var makeLink = function(id, href) {
  var link = document.createElement('a'),
    attr = {
      'id': id,
      'href': href,
      'target': '_blank',
      'style':'display:none'
    };

  link.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', href);
  return setAttributes(link, attr);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.go-btn').click(function() {
    var theLink,myLink = makeLink('the-link', $('#my-dropdown').val());

    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',myLink.outerHTML);
    theLink = document.getElementById('the-link');
    console.log(theLink);
    theLink.click();
    theLink.parentElement.removeChild(theLink);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Open in new tab - No pop up blocker</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <select id="my-dropdown" name="my-dropdown">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">A</option>
    <option value="http://www.aol.com">B</option>
    <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">C</option>
  </select>
  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
   window.open( $('#my-dropdown').val(), "_blank" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to open it in a new tab, but I don't know about window:

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
   window.open("#my-dropdown", "_blank");
});
```